# Convert Integer value to Enumeration Type

Tags: delphi

Can I be sure that *delphi* assign integer number in a ascending sequence to any enumeration a my create ?

```
type
  TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond, mtThird);
```

there for sure mtFirts is always `TmyType(1)` ???

I try to write code like  `myTypeselection   := TMyType(MyRadiogroup.ItemIndex+1);`

But I fail that the values Integer numbers  are somehow mixed .

Comment: no,  ist  TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond, mtThird);  always equivalent to   TMyType = (mtFirst=1, mtSecond=2, mtThird=3);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types) has the answer:

> By default, the ordinalities of enumerated values start from 0 and follow the sequence in which their identifiers are listed in the type declaration.

So your belief that numbering starts from one is in fact incorrect. It is the case the `ord(mtFirst)=0`, `ord(mtSecond)=1` and so on.

Which means your code should read:

```
myTypeselection := TMyType(MyRadiogroup.ItemIndex);
```

Because radio group indexing is also zero based.

In my own code, I use the following generic class to perform operations like this:

```
type
  TEnumeration<T> = class
  strict private
    class function TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; inline; static;
    class function TypeData: PTypeData; inline; static;
  public
    class function IsEnumeration: Boolean; static;
    class function ToOrdinal(Enum: T): Integer; inline; static;
    class function FromOrdinal(Value: Integer): T; inline; static;
    class function MinValue: Integer; inline; static;
    class function MaxValue: Integer; inline; static;
    class function InRange(Value: Integer): Boolean; inline; static;
    class function EnsureRange(Value: Integer): Integer; inline; static;
  end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.TypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Result := System.TypeInfo(T);
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.TypeData: PTypeData;
begin
  Result := TypInfo.GetTypeData(TypeInfo);
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.IsEnumeration: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TypeInfo.Kind=tkEnumeration;
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.ToOrdinal(Enum: T): Integer;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Assert(SizeOf(Enum)<=SizeOf(Result));
  Result := 0;
  Move(Enum, Result, SizeOf(Enum));
  Assert(InRange(Result));
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.FromOrdinal(Value: Integer): T;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Assert(InRange(Value));
  Assert(SizeOf(Result)<=SizeOf(Value));
  Move(Value, Result, SizeOf(Result));
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.MinValue: Integer;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Result := TypeData.MinValue;
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.MaxValue: Integer;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Result := TypeData.MaxValue;
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.InRange(Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ptd: PTypeData;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  ptd := TypeData;
  Result := Math.InRange(Value, ptd.MinValue, ptd.MaxValue);
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.EnsureRange(Value: Integer): Integer;
var
  ptd: PTypeData;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  ptd := TypeData;
  Result := Math.EnsureRange(Value, ptd.MinValue, ptd.MaxValue);
end;
```

With that at hand your code becomes:

```
myTypeselection := TEnumeration<TMyType>.FromOrdinal(MyRadiogroup.ItemIndex);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't specify values for your enumeration values, the compiler will start with zero, so this

```
TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond, mtThird)
```

is equivalent to

```
TMyType = (mtFirst = 0, mtSecond = 1, mtThird = 2)
```

If you use the correct start value 0, casting from integer to your enumeration and back is safe.

Comment: To be precise, your two declarations are not equivalent. The compiler won't generate RTTI for the second one.